# How to say 'the novelty has worn off' in Russian?

Tags: перевод

What would be the translation of this idiom? I can't seem to find it anywhere online and I'm not too sure if `новизна прошла` would be an accurate translation.

Comment: Sorry to cut in on your question!, but I'm curious myself how Russian speakers express the idea in this context: "you'll land back on your feet ***once the novelty wears off***". https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/16927/in-russian-how-do-you-say-air-quotes

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens ***"как только/когда пройдёт эффект новизны, ты (снова) окажешься на грешной земле"*** or ***"как только/когда улягутся новые впечатления, ты вернёшься к реальности"*** these are ad-hoc versions

Comment: in certain contexts, it can be translated as "приесться"

Answer (score 3):

Новизна (чего-либо) повыветрилась.

Это уже примелькалось.

Comment: или: "новизна исчезла"

Answer (score 3):

Впечатление новизны/свежести стерлось.

Answer (score 2):

`Пропал эффект новизны` shows many hits with search engines.

Answer (score 2):

I like Alex_ander's `Это уже примелькалось`.

Also, `Это уже не ново`, `Это уже не в новинку`.

If you're talking about a joke you can hear `Это(т анекдот) уже с бородой`.

In the internet you can hear `баян`, though that's just net language, not suitable for anything formal.

Basically, I don't think a native speaker would use the word `новизна`, I feel like it's pretty rare, though an accurate translation of "novelty".

Answer (score 1):

A slightly low-key option is `это приелось`, with an obvious reference to food.